# click event not working in IE7 in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add one function dynamically on a tag which is working fine on all browser except IE7.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(num){
if(num==1){
$('#one').removeAttr('onclick')
$('#two').attr('onclick','show(1)')
alert(0)
}}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show(1)" id="one">one</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="two">two</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add the related fiddle\

Comment: Fiddle also won't work in IE 7 :)

Comment: @DadoJerry It won't even work in 8 on my machine. 9 or higher. Chrome ftw.

Comment: Yeah that's right.....

Comment: Here is a related [jQuery attr('onclick') Problem][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781616/jquery-attronclick-problem

Comment: `$('#two').attr('onclick','show(1)')` is *not* how you attach an event handler.

Comment: It is working fine but in all browser but what is problem with ie7

Comment: @amit It may have worked, but it wasn't the correct way to do it. jQuery provides handler functions for just this purpose. Check out some of the answers below to see how jQuery handlers can be applied in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the correct way to attach/detach event handlers.
You can try using this methodology instead.

```
$('#one').off('click');
$('#two').click(function() { show(1); });
```

`.click()` is a wrapper function for `.on('click')`

Comment: I'm not sure if `.off('click')` will remove the inline `onclick` handler.

Comment: @RocketHazmat True, it most likely won't. It's not a complete solution, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jQuery, use it to register the event handlers instead of using `onclick` attribute

You can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event register since you want to call the event handler only once instead of using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
jQuery(function(){
    function handler(num){
        alert(num)
    }
    $('#one').one('click', function(){
        handler(1);
        $('#two').on('click', function(){
            handler(1);
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: @BradM sorry it was `handler(num)`

Answer (score -3):

As taken from http://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-not-working-for-ie7-8

> I have a dead simple .click() event setup for a div with the id of
>   nextLink. This works     perfectly in all the "real" browsers.
>
> ```
> $('#nextLink').click(function () {
>        alert("nextLink here");
>        });
>
>       <div id="nextLink">Next</div>
> ```

Comment: If you do copy content, please have the decency to at least give proper attribution: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-not-working-for-ie7-8