# (jQuery) How do i set a "onclick" button for a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Forgive me, for i am new to jQuery. I am creating a script which changes the page's background image on click. Though from all the tutorials i can find, i am not wise on how i can set a word to be "onclick". To make it easy, here is the script of mine that changes the background image:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('pixture').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(resources/pixture.png)');
    });
}):
</script>
```

And here is where i am trying to add the button (my fail code):

```
<h1>
    <center>
        <font face="Lithos">
            <font color="#FF0000">
                <p class="black-text-shadow">
                    <a onclick="pixture">TOGGLE BACKGROUND PIXTURE</a>
                </p>
            </font>
    </center>
</h1>
```

If anyone could help me how to properly add a "onclick" function to "TOGGLE BACKGROUND PIXTURE", i would appreciate it.

Comment: Side note, please don't use the `<center>` or `<font>` elements. They don't exist in the current HTML standard.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click

Comment: This question already exists in many formats (ie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781616/jquery-attronclick) please do not repeat questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the anchor from

```
<a onclick="pixture">TOGGLE BACKGROUND PIXTURE</a>
```

to something that is easily selectable, like an ID or a class

```
<a id="pixture">TOGGLE BACKGROUND PIXTURE</a>
```

Then you select it

```
$('#pixture').on('click', function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(resources/pixture.png)');
});
```

Also note that both the `<center>` and `<font>` tags where pretty much deprecated at least ten years ago, and shouldn't be used.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#pixture').click(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg)');
  });
});
```

```css
#pixture {
  margin : 0 auto;
  color : #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><a id="pixture">TOGGLE BACKGROUND PIXTURE</a></h1>
```

Comment: Well it works, but i was hoping for it to change the background image of the page's body, not the area surrounding the button. Any way to do so?

Comment: Then it would be `$('body')` not `$(this)`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. And one more thing, is there any way i can make this script toggle the background on and off? Or is that not possible?

Comment: Thanks a bunch once again. It's EXACTLY what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should work well

```
$(function(){
    $('picture').on('click', function(){
        //your action here
    });
});
```